# How to specify the type of a function input and output without using assert?

Tags: python, function, variables, types, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6 and would like to define a function that takes two integers `a` and `b` and returns their division `c = a//b`. I would like to enforce the input and output types without using `assert`. My understanding from what I have found in the documentations and on this site is that one should define this function as such:

```
def divide(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    c = a // b
    return c

divide(3, 2.) # Output: 1.0
```

I was expecting an error (or a warning) since `b` and `c` are not integers.

1. What is the issue with my particular code?
2. How can I specify input and output types correctly without using
   `assert` in general?

Comment: Python itself never enforces variable, parameter, or return types. It is a dynamically typed language

Comment: They're called [type _hints_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for a reason. The interpreter does not use them at all, although they are available as object attributes during runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enforcing runtime validation is currently only done by user code, for example using a 3rd party library.

One such choice is [enforce](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce):

```
>>> import enforce  # pip install enforce
>>> @enforce.runtime_validation
... def divide(a: int, b: int) -> int:
...     c = a // b
...     return c
... 
... 
>>> divide(3, 2.0)
RuntimeTypeError: 
  The following runtime type errors were encountered:
       Argument 'b' was not of type <class 'int'>. Actual type was float.
```